# Firebase auth with Mithril for login / signup in serverless SPA

Tags: firebase-authentication, mithril.js

Building a serverless Mithril.js Single Page App (SPA) using Firebase for a server-less approach and need to implement oAuth login / signup.

Anyone know a suitable library?  Can FirebaseUI play nicely with Mithril?

I saw the firebasemixin.js for for Mithril, but seems lacking the higher level functionality of eg FirebaseUI, and hoping to avoid implementing that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would be able to use mithril to draw the DOM node for FirebaseUI to attach to, and then inside the `oncreate` lifecycle event you could spin up the FireBaseUI instance.

Here's the mithril docs on [integrating with 3rd party code](https://mithril.js.org/integrating-libs.html) which shows usage of `oncreate` to initialize a library that expects a raw DOM node.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir... sounds like that would should work !  :)

Comment: Mithril + FirebaseUI example / boilerplatecode showing login / signup?  Before duplicating the proverbial coding wheel, anyone know of such a thing?  Seems like it would be a common and useful need for server-less SPAs.

Comment: I don't know of example offhand. You could always ask in [the mithril gitter](https://gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js), there's usually some active folks around helping out.